Login with google button blinks
I develop a frontend application with vue-3, and need to implement login with google.
I managed to have the entire flow working, but there is one thing that really annoys me, that the button blinks an instance after the page is loaded:

This is my simplified code:
<template>
  <div>
    <div style="height: 44px; width: 250px">
      <div id="g_id_onload"
           :data-client_id="googleClientId"
           data-callback="handleGoogleCredentialResponse"
           data-auto_prompt="false"></div>
      <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      googleClientId: import.meta.env.VITE_API_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadGoogleSdk();

  },
  methods: {
    // Load the Google SDK and render the button
    loadGoogleSdk() {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client';

      script.onload = () => {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id: this.googleClientId,
          callback: this.handleGoogleCredentialResponse,
        });
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            document.querySelector('.g_id_signin'),
            {theme: 'outline', size: 'large', shape: 'pill'}
        );
      };
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    },
  },
};
</script>

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Sounds like FOC, Have you tried hiding the button until after it's fully initialised

Can you provide a way to reproduce? It needs to be debugged what's going on. It appears that either the button or style are initialized asynchronously, but from the script I don't see why this would be the case

Probably a matter of it being hydrated and jumping because some styles are conditional.

You are using both HTML and JavaScript Sign in with Google SDK. You only need to use either one. I am guessing that is why you see the blinking issue.
